# C# Dynamic for-loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, recursion

I have users input a string in these formats:

> Example 1: A,B,C | 1,2,3 | a,b,c
>
> Example 2: A,B | C,D | E | F,G

I want to write out all the possible combinations such that:

Possible outputs for example 1:

```
A,1,a   A,2,a   A,3,a
A,1,b   A,2,b   A,3,b
A,1,c   A,2,c   A,3,c ... and so on
```

Possible outputs for example 2:

```
A,C,E,F   B,C,E,F
A,C,E,G   B,C,E,G
A,D,E,F   B,D,E,F
A,D,E,G   B,D,E,G ... and so on
```

My problem is the amount of `|` character is not constant, therefore I can't just write a fixed amount of nested for-loop, I can't hardcode this.

These input strings are actually the parameters of a command. In the end, I do not intend to just output these combinations on console. I want to send commands that looks like: COMMAND A 1 a, COMMAND A 1 b, etc.

I am not seeking for a code for me to copy and paste. I just can't get the algorithm behind this problem I encountered.

I have tried a lot of different for-loops but nothing worked, and I feel that my approach is getting further from the solution, so I simply need someone to point me to the right direction for me to understand the concept and at the end of the day I still have to do my own code in order to get what I want.

Comment: I can't see any for loop here! Have you tried anything?

Comment: You really get a string like this: `A,B,C | 1,2,3 | a,b,c` ?

Comment: You could use 'split' to separate into different arrays and then know how many '|' there are...

Comment: @BugFinder I tried, I use nested for-loop, outer loop splits `|` and inner loop splits `,` but that's definitely wrong. My brain just can't comprehend the algorithm for this that's why I'm asking. I know I'm missing a key point here, I think need a dynamic nested loop and I don't know how at all.

Comment: @S.Akbari Yes. I'm not asking about a basic for-loop question here, I need the numbers of loop to be dynamic. And honestly I have nothing to show at all. I didnt even know which approach to take (thanks to some answers now I know I should try recursion)

Comment: `int x = 5; //whatever your length is, example` then `for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)` boom dynamic loop? :O

Comment: @Kritner sorry English is not my first language, I mean the number of loop nests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done without recursion.

```
var s = "A,B,C|1,2|a|u,v,w";
var u = s.Split('|').Select(v => v.Split(',')).ToList();

var buffer = new List<string>();
buffer.Add("COMMAND ");
while (u.Count > 0)
{
    var t = from a in buffer
            from b in u.First()
            select a + ' ' + b;

    buffer = t.ToList();
    u.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

The `buffer` list will contain the "recursive outer join" combined strings afterwards.

Comment: Thank you! Something I don't quite understand: If I were to remove `buffer.Add("COMMAND ")` and `from a in buffer` (and of course no more `select a`), then I would only add first element from `u` List into `buffer` List right? How come when I did that, I only get `u,v,w` in my `buffer` list? I'm missing the LinQ concept here.

Comment: `u` is a list of arrays of strings. The `from b in u.First()` is actually a loop over the elements of the first array in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion can help you here. Consider the following:

The solution to `X, Y | ...` can be computed by computing the solution to `...`, looping over `X, Y` and prepending each option to `...`. Thus, you get away with *one* loop and a recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Write a recursive function.

Say you have `data[][]` to hold the input. Have something like:

```
solution[]
void printall(data[][], int level) {
  if (level>data.size()) print solution;
  for (c in data[level]) {
    solution[level] = c;
    printall(data, level +1);
  }
}
```

Comment: No, it's not. This is not even a proper C# fragment. And the recursion is just a wasteful way to implement iteration over the other `data` array.

Answer (score -1):

```
var input = "A,B,C | 1,2,3 | a,b,c".Replace(' ','');
var groups = input.split('|');
var a = groups[0].split(",");
var b = groups[1].split(",");
var c = groups[2].split(",");

foreach(var x int a)
    foreach(var y in b)
        foreach(var z in c)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x+y+z);
        }
```

Comment: the number of | varies

Comment: ah, sorry, din't see it metioned